# In a select add fake rows when a columns have a specifc value

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select, rows

My query is:

```
SELECT email,price
FROM invoice
WHERE email='123@xxx.com'
```

I would like to add a fake row every time the field 'price' is equal to '99.00' for every result white the value price '21.00'

Example

Normal result

```
Email         Price
123@xxx.com   84,00
123@xxx.com   99,00
123@xxx.com   29,00
123@xxx.com   99,00
```

I would like result like this:

```
Email         Price
123@xxx.com   84,00
123@xxx.com   99,00
123@xxx.com   21,00
123@xxx.com   29,00
123@xxx.com   99,00
123@xxx.com   21,00
```

Comment: Do you want to add the fake row to the table or just to the SELECT?

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: only for select not a insert

Comment: primary key is email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below query to get the expected(modified in order) results
If you use this query you won't get the results in the order

```
Email         Price
123@xxx.com   84,00
123@xxx.com   99,00
123@xxx.com   21,00
123@xxx.com   29,00
123@xxx.com   99,00
123@xxx.com   21,00
```

However you will get in the below order

```
Email         Price
123@xxx.com   84,00
123@xxx.com   99,00
123@xxx.com   29,00
123@xxx.com   99,00
123@xxx.com   21,00
123@xxx.com   21,00
```

The Query to use is

```
SELECT email,price
FROM invoice
WHERE email='123@xxx.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT email,21,00
FROM invoice
WHERE email='123@xxx.com'
AND Price=99,00
```